# Android spinner with different icons (images) in different positions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am new to Android. I want to set different icon (images) at different position of spinner item. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a custom dialog.

What you basically want to do is create a custom dialog and put your own animation in there.
There are a couple of ways to do animation, but I prefer to use animation lists. You can look up how to use them here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

If you don't have a series of images to create an animation list an alterative might be animate your image using a translate or rotate animation. Here's a really great link on how to do that. http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/06/android-development-more-animations-part-1/

After you figure out how to make an animation, all you have to do is put in a dialog.
Look here for how to do that: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Hope that helps!